# Undo the effect of "sloped" option in tikzstyle

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have defined (for example) :
`tikzstyle{text_st} =[thick, red, sloped]`

Later on, I want to use these option for node text like
 `\path (a) -- (b) node[text_st] {Nice}`

Now, if I want to use this predefined option `text_st` except for the `sloped`, how can I do that? Is there some variable like unsloped such that I can do
`\path (a) -- (b) node[text_st, unsloped] {Nice}`?

Comment: `sloped=false`. Using `sloped` issues `sloped=true` (which issues `\pgfslopedattimetrue`).

Comment: Aside: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52372/should-tikzset-or-tikzstyle-be-used-to-define-tikz-styles

Comment: @DurgaDatta did `sloped=false` resolve your problem? What is the status of this question?

Comment: @PaulGessler Answer these viciously :) This one I did it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The manual could have been better here but this is actually a boolean setting key. It sets the TeX conditional `\ifpgfslopedattime`

Hence when you have a style, you can turn the `sloped` effect off with setting it to `false`

```
\documentstyle[tikz]{standalone}

\tikzset{text_st/.style={thick, red, sloped}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={text_st,draw}]
%....
\path (a) -- (b) node[text_st,sloped=false] {Nice};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```